# Missing on data with Group by and Sum

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to make sense of the group by clause in a specific case: I joined two tables that are supposed to have the same dollar amount for each invoice, so I'm trying to make a Query to confirm there is no discrepancy. Here is the tables, query and result:

```
Table A:
Order_Number | Order_Number_Line | Amount
1            | 1                 | 80
1            | 2                 | 20
1            | 3                 | 30
1            | 4                 | 70

Table B

Order_Number | Order_Number_Line | Invoice_ID | Invoice_Line_Number | Amount
1            | 1                 | 1234       | 1                   | 20
1            | 2                 | 1234       | 2                   | 5
1            | 3                 | 1234       | 3                   | 10
1            | 4                 | 1234       | 4                   | 25
1            | 1                 | 1234       | 1                   | 35
1            | 2                 | 1234       | 2                   | 7
1            | 3                 | 1234       | 3                   | 15
1            | 4                 | 1234       | 4                   | 10
1            | 1                 | 1234       | 1                   | 25
1            | 2                 | 1234       | 2                   | 8
1            | 3                 | 1234       | 3                   | 5
1            | 4                 | 1234       | 4                   | 35

Select A.Order_Number, A.Amount, B.Amount
From Table_A as A
Left Join (Select Order_Number, Amount From Table_B) as B
On A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number

Order_Number  |  Amount_Table_A  |  Amount_Table_B 
01            |  80              |   20            
01            |  80              |   5            
01            |  80              |   10            
01            |  80              |   25            
01            |  80              |   35            
01            |  80              |   7            
01            |  80              |   15           
01            |  80              |   10         
01            |  80              |   25            
01            |  80              |   8          
01            |  80              |   5           
01            |  80              |   35
01            |  20              |   20            
01            |  20              |   5            
01            |  20              |   10            
01            |  20              |   25            
01            |  20              |   35            
01            |  20              |   7            
01            |  20              |   15           
01            |  20              |   10         
01            |  20              |   25            
01            |  20              |   8          
01            |  20              |   5           
01            |  20              |   35
01            |  30              |   20            
01            |  30              |   5            
01            |  30              |   10            
01            |  30              |   25            
01            |  30              |   35            
01            |  30              |   7            
01            |  30              |   15           
01            |  30              |   10         
01            |  30              |   25            
01            |  30              |   8          
01            |  30              |   5           
01            |  30              |   35
01            |  70              |   20            
01            |  70              |   5            
01            |  70              |   10            
01            |  70              |   25            
01            |  70              |   35            
01            |  70              |   7            
01            |  70              |   15           
01            |  70              |   10         
01            |  70              |   25            
01            |  70              |   8          
01            |  70              |   5           
01            |  70              |   35
```

I tried using group by, but only got the first amount record for each table:

```
Select A.Order_Number, A.Amount, B.Amount
From Table_A as A
Left Join (Select Order_Number, Amount From Table_B) as B
On A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number
Group By A.Order_Number

 Invoice_ID  |  Amount_Table_A  |  Amount_Table_B  |
 01          |  80              |  20              |
```

I tried adding the sum() clause to each amount attribute in the select statement and got the sum of each repeated record:

```
Select A.Order_Number, sum(A.Amount), sum(B.Amount)
From Table_A as A
Left Join (Select Order_Number, Amount From Table_B) as B
On A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number
Group By A.Order_Number

 Invoice_ID  |  Amount_Table_A  |  Amount_Table_B  |
 01          |  2400            |  800             |
```

how may I modify this query to show the real value?? Expected value is:

```
 Invoice_ID  |  Amount_Table_A  |  Amount_Table_B  |
 01          |  200             |  200             |
```

Please keep in mind that this is an over simplified data set. The real table has over a million records and I need to make sure that the Invoice_ID adds up to the same total in both tables.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Can you please post first 10-20 records from both the tables A & B. And also the desired output you need computing on that 10-20 records. That would help better to understand what you need.

Comment: I've just edited the question so you have access to the data set. The desired output is the Expected value: 200 for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if this works for you.

```
SELECT 
    A.Order_Number, A.Amount AS A_Amount, B.Amount AS B_Amount
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Order_Number, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM
        A
    GROUP BY Order_Number) A
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Order_Number, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM
        B
    GROUP BY Order_Number) B ON A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number
```

Comment: It worked!! Is there recommended literature to understand the way queries work? I would have never gotten to build it this way

Answer (score 1):

You're close, try this. It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do but I hope this helps. It appears that you aren't being selective enough in your join.

```
Select A.Order_Number, SUM(A.Amount), SUM(B.Amount)
From Table_A as A
Left Join Table_B as B
On A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number AND A.Order_Line_Number = B.Order_Line_Number
Group By A.Order_Number
```

Comment: This almost works! I'm editing the question and adding your fix. The B.Amount came out correctly but the A.Amount came out as 3X the correct A.Amount. 

My goal is to run a query that will show A.Amount and B.Amount for all my Order_Numbers. In this example I'm using just 1 order number, but I have thousands. I want to make sure that the amounts in Table A and B are synchronized.